# How do i navigate backward and refresh the page i have navigated to?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using App.RootFrame.GoBack(); but it does not refresh the page (which makes sense).

I would like to enforce a page refresh... Anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610343/refresh-or-update-page-on-click-of-back-button-wp7).

In any event, you probably want to use the NavigationService as follows:

```
if(NavigationService.CanGoBack())
{
    NavigationService.GoBack();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // ensure view has the data it needs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to do the job well.

```
IEnumerable<JournalEntry> pages = App.RootFrame.BackStack;
string pageURL = pages.First().Source.OriginalString;
App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri(pageURL + "?Refresh=true&random=" + Guid.NewGuid(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: Then you must call `PhoneApplicationFrame.RemoveBackEntry()` twice in new page's `OnNavigatedTo` for "refresh" effect.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did do this... Although i'm sure this is not the best technique.. I will re-visit it at a later date... as it's working well atm!

Answer (score 0):

on a 'GoBack()' the OnNavigatedTo() method will be run, but the constructor for the page won't be. Therefore you need to refresh the page yourself in the OnNavigatedTo() method.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Refresh the data in here
}
```

Also I would suspect that you would be better of using the navigationservice to go back i.e:

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```